# angularJS how to $eval the function with parameter

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement the directive, in the directive, I want to $eval the values which contains the function name and parameter value:

Html page:

```
<select mydirective="action('pValue')">
```

AngularJS directive code:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.$eval(attr.mydirective);
        });
    }
}
```

What I am expected is it will invoke the action function define in scope and pass the pValue as function parameter. How can I make it work please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want happen automatically, the function will invoke with the value, this is the purpose of eval:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.action = function(val) {
    alert(val);
  }

});

app.directive('mydirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, element, attr) {

      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$eval(attr.mydirective);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select mydirective="action('pValue')"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: How could I pass element $event to method action? <select mydirective="action($event, 'pValue')"></select>

Comment: @tuananh if you want to capture event object you need to bind e.g. onclick event for this select. You dont have to change function params inside select: mydirective="action('pValue')". Inside action function just check event param: alert(val, event);

Answer (score 1):

For those whom looking for a way to pass $event info to custom directive method see example below:

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<div on-touch-end="onTouchEnd( 'some data' )">
   TOUCH ME!
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
$scope.onTouchEnd = function( data ) {
    console.log("onTouchEnd event with data", data, event );
};
```

**DIRECTIVE:**

```
.directive('onTouchEnd', function() {
    return {
        restrict    : 'A',
        link        : function( $scope, $element, $attr ) {
            $element.on('touchend', function( event ) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.$eval( $attr.onTouchEnd );
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```